# Spring RestTemplate: sending array / list of String in GET request

Tags: java, android, arrays, spring, resttemplate

I'm trying to send a array / list of String to my REST server through Spring RestTemplate.

This is on my android side:

```
        private List<String> articleids = new ArrayList<>();
        articleids.add("563e5aeb0eab252dd4368ab7");
        articleids.add("563f2dbd9bb0152bb0ea058e");         

        final String url = "https://10.0.3.2:5000/getsubscribedarticles";

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
                .queryParam("articleids", articleids);
        java.net.URI builtUrl = builder.build().encode().toUri();
        Log.e("builtUrl", builtUrl.toString());
```

The builtUrl is:  https://10.0.3.2:5000/getsubscribedarticles?articleids=%5B563e5aeb0eab252dd4368ab7,%20563f2dbd9bb0152bb0ea058e%5D

On the server side:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getsubscribedarticles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Posts> getSubscribedPostFeed(@RequestParam("articleids") List<String> articleids){
     for (String articleid : articleids {
        logger.info(" articleid : " + articleid);
    }
}
```

The server logs:

> .13:11:35.370 [http-nio-8443-exec-5] INFO  c.f.s.i.ServiceGatewayImpl
>   -  articleid : [563e5aeb0eab252dd4368ab7
>
> .13:11:35.370 [http-nio-8443-exec-5] INFO  c.f.s.i.ServiceGatewayImpl
>   -  articleid : 563f2dbd9bb0152bb0ea058e]

Which I can see is wrong as the list should not have a '[' on the first item and a ']' on the last item.

I have read this thread [How to pass List or String array to getForObject with Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507129/how-to-pass-list-or-string-array-to-getforobject-with-spring-resttemplate) but it does not actually answer the question.

The selected answer issues out a POST request, but I want to do a GET request , also it requires an additional object to work to hold the list and I would prefer to not create extra objects if I can do it with Spring RestTemplate natively.

Answer (score 19):

Using Java 8, this worked for me :

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = fromHttpUrl(url);
builder.queryParam("articleids", String.join(",", articleids));
URI uri = builder.build().encode().toUri();
```

It forms the URL like:

```
https://10.0.3.2:5000/getsubscribedarticles?articleids=123,456,789
```

Answer (score 15):

I would expect that the correct working url is something like:

```
https://10.0.3.2:5000/getsubscribedarticles?articleids[]=123&articleids[]=456&articleids[]=789
```

After a quick look at the code of `public UriComponentsBuilder queryParam(String name, Object... values)`, I would solve it by using `UriComponentsBuilder` this way:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
    .queryParam("articleids[]", articleids.toArray(new String[0]));
```

It is important that, the second parameter is an `array` but not an Object/Collection!

Answer (score 1):

You did everything correct. You just need to call it without the `[]`.

Just invoke it with `.../getsubscribedarticles/articleids=foo,bar,42`

I tested this with Spring Boot 1.2.6 and it works like this.

Comment: thanks for your answer - i did solve my problem in a similar way, see my answer below

Comment: I strongly believe that this is wrong. `articleids` is part of the query part of the url, and therefore `@RequestParam` should been used but not @PathVariable - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable - so in order to use `@PathVariable` it would been required also to modified the url so that the query parameter become an part of the path

Comment: @Ralph You are right. I updated the answer and removed the part talking about PathVariables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dOx for his suggestion - I managed to solve this with the PathVariable - i set the list in my url for android:

```
    final String url = "https://10.0.3.2:5000/getsubscribedarticles/"+new ArrayList<>(articleids);
```

For my rest server:

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/getsubscribedarticles/[{articleids}]", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Posts> getSubscribedPostFeed(@PathVariable String[] articleids){

}
```