# how to pass List<Objects> as body in POST METHOD (RestTemplate)

Tags: java, spring, list, resttemplate

I'm trying to make a Post request using restTemplate,the problem is the API is accepting `List<Users>` in the body as POST Request

```
public class Users {

    String id;

    String name;

    String gender;

}
```

I've added the elements as

```
List<Users> userList=new ArrayList<Users>();
userList.add(new Users("1","AA","Male"));
userList.add(new Users("2","BB","Male"));
userList.add(new Users("3","CC","Female"));
```

AS

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response =  restTemplate.postForEntity(URL.toString(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

Here how should I pass my userList into the request Body?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507129/how-to-pass-list-or-string-array-to-getforobject-with-spring-resttemplate/22681537 will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your data in HttpEntity.You can use ObjectMapper which is from jackson-databind lib to convert your list  to json.

```
String userJsonList = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userList);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(userJsonList, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response =  restTemplate.postForEntity(URL.toString(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

So basically it will pass the data as json string.

Answer (score 0):

For Post request you can use "method=RequestMethod.POST" or @POST annotation with your method.
And for list object please check below code. It will work.

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Users>> methodName(@QueryParam("id") String id){
List<Users> userList=new ArrayList<Users>();
userList.add(new Users("1","AA","Male"));
userList.add(new Users("2","BB","Male"));
userList.add(new Users("3","CC","Female"));

return new ResponseEntity<List<Users>>(userList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```