# How to use Spring`s RestTemplate to POST an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, spring, post, resttemplate

I am trying to post a simple array of strings using the spring`s restTemplate. Did anyone succeed with that ?

The client:

```
    public void save(){
        String company = "12345";
        String productId = "10";
        String[] colors = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
        String convertUrl = "http://localhost:8080/cool-web/save";
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> convertVars = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        convertVars.add("companyID", StringUtils.trimToEmpty(company));
        convertVars.add("productId", StringUtils.trimToEmpty(productId));
        convertVars.add("disclaimer", StringUtils.trimToEmpty("ffs"));
        convertVars.add("colorsArray", colors); 
        restTemplate.postForObject(convertUrl, null, String.class, convertVars);
}
```

The Service is:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void save(@RequestParam("colorsArray[]") String[] colors,
        @RequestParam("disclaimer") String disclaimer,
        @RequestParam("companyID") String companyID,
        @RequestParam("productId") String productId) {

    resourceService.save(colors, disclaimer, companyID, productId);
}
```

I got 400 Bad Request.

What am I doing wrong ?

I am using the default messageConverters.

Do I need to implement custom messageConverter for a simple array of Strings ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution:

```
public void save(){

    String company = "12345";
    String productId = "10";
    String[] colors = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
    String convertUrl = "http://localhost:8080/cool-web/save";

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> convertVars = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

    convertVars.add("companyID", StringUtils.trimToEmpty(company));
    convertVars.add("productId", StringUtils.trimToEmpty(productId));
    convertVars.add("disclaimer", StringUtils.trimToEmpty("ffs"));

    for(String color:colors){
        convertVars.add("colorsArray[]", color); 
    }

    restTemplate.postForObject(convertUrl, convertVars , String.class); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying POST `MultiValueMap`, use `Map.class` instead of `String.class` in the code:

```
restTemplate.postForObject(convertUrl, null, Map.class, convertVars);
```

And your service method is wrong I guess. Because you are posting `MultiValueMap` and in `save` method you are trying to get all the internal variables as method parameters i.e. RequestParam.
That's not going to happen. You will have to accept only `MultiValueMap` there and take things out of it for use.

```
public void save(@RequestParam("colorsArray[]") MultiValueMap<String, Object> convertVars ) {
    resourceService.save(convertVars.getColors(), .... );
}
```

Comment: String.class is the response type so it should not be Map.class. The map is used to build the request`s body so the service should not receive as an argument Map. Nevertheless I tried your suggestions it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestParam(value)`  value - "The name of the request parameter to bind to." So `@RequestParam("colorsArray[]") String[] colors` trying to find param with name "colorsArray[]" but u put parameter with name "colorsArray". May be that is the reason.